# Scala Try's toOption method returns Some(null)

Tags: scala

Should `Success` (the child of Try) return `Some(null)` when converting it to `Option`?

E.g. 
`Try(null).toOption` in scala 2.11.7 returns `Some(null)`
Success's `toOption` method implemented simply by returning `Some(value)`.
Why doesn't it return `None` when converting `Try` to option using `toOption` method if underlying value of try is `null`?

Comment: `null` is a valid (albeit dangerous) value so `toOption` should preserve it. Converting a `Try` to an `Option` discards the error, not the value.

Comment: ...yet `Option(null)` is `None` making it somewhat confusing

Comment: As `Option(null)` produces `None` `toOption` in whatever class should behave similarly, IMHO

Comment: `Option.apply` is the exception, not the rule. It exists primarily to get rid of nulls since (as you've found) other Option stuff doesn't.

Comment: `Some(null)` is perverse. IMO the API should be optimised for the safety and the common sense not preserving information at all costs.  If people require `toOption` to preserve `Some(null)` they should be use pattern matching on the original `Try`.  The current situation is an example of the tail wagging the dog. https://twitter.com/yoshihiro503/status/639276748987699200

Comment: @iain No Some(null) is not perverse, Option(null) == None is.  Option is a collection with size 0 or 1, expecting Some(null) to be any different than List(null) is insanity.  I completely agree that Scala should have some Option-like construct that disallows null values, but Option is not it.  What would you want List(null, "x").headOption to return?  None?  Absolutely not!

Answer (score 6):

Here's the source of `toOption` from Scala 2.11.7:

```
def toOption: Option[T] = if (isSuccess) Some(get) else None
```

I agree with Bruno that this is confusing, it should probably read

```
def toOption: Option[T] = if (isSuccess) Option(get) else None
```

Comment: Returning null is confusing. Your suggestion assumes null is indistinguishable from failure. It's easier to just `toOption.filter(_ != null)` or if you do it often, dealing with Java APIs perhaps, make it an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not.  Option is NOT a null-safety container, it is a Functor, a Monad, and a Collection of size 0 or 1.  It can contain null, just like a List can.  Just like Try can.

Although it is often used for null-safety, due to Option.apply converting null to None and general Scala best practices avoiding the use of null.

Furthermore, the language does not allow you to define a type parameter that is not null, so `Try[A]` is implicitly saying that A can be null, according to the language, and `Option[A]` means that the value can be null too.  It is only by convention that A usually is not null.

It would be incorrect to convert a Try containing a null value to None, as it would be truncating the range of A implicitly.  `Some[A](null)` is valid, for any `A` that is an `AnyRef`

The language design is at odds with its own best practices here.  The language does next-to-nothing to help enforce it.  Null is a valid bottom type.  An ideal world would allow users to define non-nullable types and the compiler to track null introduction and elimination, which would eliminate these sorts of surprises.

Note that if we made `toOption` convert null values to None, then the following equality would not hold:

```
val t: Try = ...
t.toOption.map(f) == t.map(f).toOption
```

which could lead to *other* surprises in your code when seemingly harmless refactorings were done, perhaps some minor for comprehension rearrangement that suddenly changes a result from None to something else because of the order of operations that appear to be order independent.

Scala should have had two types for this, one which is a null safety container (`Maybe` ?) and breaks the law above in general, because it can not contain null, and another that is just like today's Option, but without Option.apply -- an optional value.

Option.apply is the odd man out, and should be removed, IMO.

For example, consider the following, all of which evaluate to `Some(null)`:

```
Some(Some(null)).flatten
List("a", null).find(s != "a")
List(null, "blah").headOption
Try(null).toOption
```

Option is used all across the collections library to be a collection of size 0 or 1, and *not a null safety device*.  It makes no sense for these to return None as long as Option is a primarily collection of size 0 or 1, and not a 'non-null' wrapper.   If Option was such a thing, then it would not be used across the collections library to represent optional values, such as with `find` and `headOption` above.

If anyone truly wants to get into the weeds on the topic, have fun:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/1DXdknjt9pY/_moEcbNd4noJ

5 years ago I thought it was a great idea to get rid of `Some(null)`.  Now I would propose getting rid of `Option.apply` and creating a different type for non-nullness.  Call it `Maybe`.  Then one could have `Try.toMaybe` along side `Try.toOption`

Comment: Not my opinion. Knowing that Option(null) gives you None, you can simply expect Try({null}).toOption to be None, too. As iain told above in the comments, the tail shouldn't be wagging the dog.

Comment: @GerhardHagerer That argument falls apart in the face of things like List(null, "blah").headOption -- Knowing that Option(null) gives you None, would you expect None as a result?  NO!  Option is primarily a collection of size 0 or 1.  Option.apply is the exception.